# RDP Client for Mac with File Copy&Paste Feature

Tags: remote-desktop

Is there any RDP client, that allows to copy&paste files to/from host machine.
RDC for Windows (at least the last one) does it, RDC for Mac 2.1.1 does not.

Answer (score 1):

iTap RDP for Mac (http://itap-mobile.com/desktop/rdp/) supports clipboard redirection and a bunch of advanced RDP features (RemoteFX, TS Gateway to name a few). I use it on a daily basis.

Comment: Unforunately no clipboard function for files (to/from host), so it is no solution for my problem.